# Did I find an Xcode 7.0.1 bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, orientation, xcode7

Xcode 6.1 I had no issues with code, in fact apple approved my app. Now updated to Xcode 7.0.1 and a strange error appears with device orientation. I use UIInterfaceOrientationMask for Portrait and PortraitUpsideDown orientation. But when I click on my Facebook share button implemented with Social Framework's SLComposeViewController, it ONLY stays in Portrait orientation even if I'm holding device in UpsideDown orientation. However, this ONLY happens when I'm using the iPhone. The iPad has the exact same Objective-C code as iPhone but the iPad doesn't have this issue.

So is this an Xcode 7.0.1 bug and if so can I ignore it and Apple would re-approve the app with an update i'm doing? How do I report a bug to Apple?

Comment: Do you have the portrait lock enabled on your iPhone by any chance?

Comment: Portrait turns to Upside down normally if you flip app. It just doesn't turn upside down if I click the Facebook share button.

Comment: Mate, No, I didn't say that the device orientation doesn't flip when you flip the iPhone. I said the device orientation doesn't flip when you flip the iPhone only AFTER you click on the Facebook Share button.